# How do I get tidy to do what I want?

Tags: html, tidy

I'm trying to get tidy to convert a html document to xml document on windows But there should be no additional linebreaks (markup shall stay)
I would believe that the following command line should do the trick, but somehow it's not working.

```
tidy --markup no -o Output.xml -file o.txt -asxml Input.html
```

Can someone help?

By the way,

```
tidy -o Output.xml -file o.txt -asxml Input.html
```

works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tidy?

Can you provide an input sample and the expected output?

(Sorry, I'm not good enough to comment.)

A possible place to *also* ask this question is the Tidy bug tracker: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues, but please provide the samples as requested.